# Error running Remote debugging with "ptvsd"

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've started remote debugging with visual studio code but I cant get it to work. Both the remote and the local development PC both running version 4.1.3 of ptvsd.  The remote machine has the script :

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach()

#Enable the below line of code only if you want the application to wait untill the debugger has att$
#ptvsd.wait_for_attach()

import random


guesses_made = 0
name = input('Hello! What is your name?\n')
number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, {0}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.'.format(name))

while guesses_made < 6:
    guess = int(input('Take a guess: '))
    guesses_made += 1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number:
    print('Good job, {0}! You guessed my number in {1} guesses!'.format(name, guesses_made))
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was {0}'.format(number))
```

The local computer is :

```
import ptvsd
ptvsd.enable_attach(address = ('192.34.98.197',3000))

#Enable the below line of code only if you want the application to wait untill the debugger has attached to it
#ptvsd.wait_for_attach()

import random

guesses_made = 0
name = input('Hello! What is your name?\n')
number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, {0}, I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.'.format(name))

while guesses_made < 6:
    guess = int(input('Take a guess: '))
    guesses_made += 1
    if guess < number:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    if guess > number:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number:
    print('Good job, {0}! You guessed my number in {1} guesses!'.format(name, guesses_made))
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was {0}'.format(number))
```

I've added the entries into launch.json :

```
{
    "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "remoteRoot": "/home/pi/testdebug/",
    "port": 3000,
    "secret": "my_secret",
    "host":"localhost"
},
```

This is the error i receive:

```
> PS C:\IOT\Github\RaspberryPi\test_remote_debug> python
> .\test_remote_debug.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> ".\test_remote_debug.py", line 2, in <module>
>     ptvsd.enable_attach(address = ('192.34.98.197',3000))   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\attach_server.py", line 72,
> in enable_attach
>     redirect_output=redirect_output,   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_remote.py", line 85, in
> enable_attach
>     suspend=False)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
> line 1313, in settrace
>     stop_at_frame,   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
> line 1362, in _locked_settrace
>     debugger.connect(host, port)  # Note: connect can raise error.   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
> line 355, in connect
>     s = start_client(host, port)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\pydevd_hooks.py", line 85,
> in <lambda>
>     _start_client = (lambda h, p: start_client(daemon, h, p))   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_remote.py", line 72, in
> <lambda>
>     start_client=(lambda daemon, h, port: start_daemon()),   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_remote.py", line 64, in
> start_daemon
>     _, next_session = daemon.start_server(addr=(host, port))   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\daemon.py", line 157, in
> start_server
>     self._server = create_server(addr.host, addr.port)   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\socket.py", line 77, in
> create_server
>     server.bind((host, port)) OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context PS
> C:\IOT\Github\RaspberryPi\test_remote_debug> python
> .\test_remote_debug.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> ".\test_remote_debug.py", line 2, in <module>
>     ptvsd.enable_attach(address = ('192.34.98.197',3000))   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\attach_server.py", line 72,
> in enable_attach
>     redirect_output=redirect_output,   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_remote.py", line 85, in
> enable_attach
>     suspend=False)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
> line 1313, in settrace
>     stop_at_frame,   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
> line 1362, in _locked_settrace
>     debugger.connect(host, port)  # Note: connect can raise error.   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py",
> line 355, in connect
>     s = start_client(host, port)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\pydevd_hooks.py", line 85,
> in <lambda>
>     _start_client = (lambda h, p: start_client(daemon, h, p))   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_remote.py", line 72, in
> <lambda>
>     start_client=(lambda daemon, h, port: start_daemon()),   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\_remote.py", line 64, in
> start_daemon
>     _, next_session = daemon.start_server(addr=(host, port))   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\daemon.py", line 157, in
> start_server
>     self._server = create_server(addr.host, addr.port)   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\ptvsd\socket.py", line 77, in
> create_server
>     server.bind((host, port)) OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

If anyone has any ideas how to correct this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `launch.json` is out-of-date as it's configured for the old debugger. Please see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging for the latest instructions (e.g. `localRoot` and `remoteRoote` should be under `pathMappings`).

Comment: Brilliant a step closer, im now getting the local and remote computer to talk to each other.  im getting the following message twice :

pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /home/pi/testdebug/C:/IOT/Github/RaspberryPi/test_remote_debug/test_remote_debug.py (will have no effect).  Any ideas why?

Comment: p.s. I've created another questions at as its a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760636/ptvsd-with-visual-studio-code-pydev-debugger-warning-trying-to-add-breakpoint

Comment: Your paths don't look set up appropriately for `localRoot` and `remoteRoot`. If you look at `/home/pi/testdebug/C:/IOT/Github/RaspberryPi/test_remote_debug/test_remote_debug.py` you will notice that you seem to have some UNIX path prepended to a Windows path.