# ptvsd with visual studio code "pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist"

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

When I run the following debug from a Visual studio code (Windows computer) to a Raspberry PI.  I get the following error twice :

```
pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /home/pi/testdebug/C:/IOT/Github/RaspberryPi/test_remote_debug/test_remote_debug.py (will have no effect)

pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /home/pi/testdebug/C:/IOT/Github/RaspberryPi/ReadPressure/Testing_bar_broke_notification.py (will have no effect)
```

This is the setting in the lauch.json :

```
{
    "name": "Python Attach (Remote Debug blah blah )",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "pathMappings": [
        {
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",  // You may also manually specify the directory containing your source code.
            "remoteRoot": "/home/pi/testdebug/" // Linux example; adjust as necessary for your OS and situation.
        }
    ],
    "port": 3000,                   // Set to the remote port.
    "host": "192.34.98.197"               // Set to your remote host's public IP address.
}
```

Any ideas why im getting to get this to work ?

Comment: Can you try specifying an absolute path for `localRoot`? The paths you are showing in the message look to have your `localRoot` prepended to your `remoteRoot`. Also make sure you are using the latest version of the Python extension as a bug related to this was fixed a little while ago.

Comment: Hello, I've tried specifying a local root but I have the same problem.   Both the remote and the local development PC both running version 4.1.3 of ptvsd. i did notice json did not like the "\" on Windows (local computer) so changed them to "/" i.e  C:/IOT/test_remote_debug.  Still no look.  Any other ideas?

Comment: just to confirm, the message is still same "pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /home/pi/testdebug/C:/IOT/Github/RaspberryPi/test_remote_debug/test_remote_debug.py (will have no effect)"

Comment: Then please file an issue at github.com/microsoft/vscode-python .

Comment: thanks, ill do that

Comment: i think i may have found the problem, see question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927559/visual-studio-code-python-selector-defaults-to-version-2-even-when-python-v3-se?noredirect=1#comment92764583_52927559.  Any ideas?

Comment: Having the same issue on Windows (local path `C:/...` getting appended to remote path on remote system) - any solution? Seems to work when I specify a literal path for `localPath` but would prefer to keep the configuration portable

Answer (score 3):

If it's a local file on `localhost` you can use:

```
       "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Verify "remoteRoot" in launch.json. set the  actual path