# visual studio code: python selector defaults to version 2 even when python v3 selected

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code runs Python2 even when Python3 interpreter is selected. I run the code by pressing the play button at the top right.  I've changed the workstation and user settings python.pythonpath to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" just incase.   I've included a screen capture below of the file im running and the output :

[image]

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be and how i can correct it?

Much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that opens up a Command Line and your usual `PATH` applies. Try setting `PYTHONPATH` to Python3 and opening Visual Studio Code from that command line. If that works, have a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments.

Comment: when i run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" it open python3.  Shouldnt visual studio open python3?

Comment: can you explain further what you meant?  I may have miss-understood.

Comment: What I mean is that your `PATH` might be overriding your setting in Visual Studio Code. Try opening up a Command Line and see the result of `python --version`.

Comment: C:\Users\john>python --version  ***next line*** 
Python 3.7.0

Comment: OK my theory was wrong. Now I spot 3.7 at the bottom-left corner of your screenshot too.

Comment: any ideas on where to go with  this one?

Comment: From the command prompt (outside of visual studio code), i type python and it opens python3.  Inside of visual studio code i type python and it opens python2, weird.  If i type py inside visual studio code command prompt it opens python3.  Any idea why im getting this strange behaviour?

Comment: I changed the code-runner.executorMap from "python" to "py -u" and now opens up python3.  All the code i write is in python3 anyway so should be ok for me.  Howerver, im not sure what would happen if i need to write/edit python2 code

Answer (score 0):

That's expected. You need to create a virtual environment that gets activated to make the `python` command point to something other than whatever your `PATH` has as `python`.